# crontabの設定をするときにGNU nanoが開くのですが、VS Codeに変更したいです。

Tags: shellscript, cron

`crontab`の設定をするときに開くテキストエディタをVS Code Insider版に変更したいので、下記のShellScriptを`./profile`に追記して実行したのですが、どうしてもGNU nanoが開いてしまいます。

`crontab`の設定をするときに開くテキストエディタを変更する方法をご教授願います。

```
echo export EDITOR=code-insiders >> /home/pi/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: シェル起動直後に「echo $VISUAL」と「echo $EDITOR」を実行すると何が表示されますか?

Comment: @int32_t 空白行が一行表示されます。

Comment: 質問文一段落目の `./profile` というファイル名は正しいですか? ホームディレクトリは `/home/pi` ですか?

Comment: @int32_t 正確には`profile`でした。ホームディレクトリは`/home/pi`です。

Answer (score 0):

どんなシェルをお使いかわかりませんが、一般的なものなら `/profile` も `~/profile` も自動で実行されないでしょう。もし提示されているコードが `~/.profile` に書かれていたら、`source ~/.profile` により無限再帰になります。

`~/.profile` の中に、

```
export EDITOR=code-insiders
```

と書いてシェルを起動し直してください。